# Coding a character to go to the opposite side when exceeding the stage width

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

Basically, I've made it so that my "player" in my game doesn't exceed the stage width (only moves along the x axis) and so when it gets to the edge it just stops.  However, I want to make it so that if the player exceeds the width on the left side it will flow in from the right and vice versa.  This is the code I have at the minute which is what stops it from leaving the stage area:

```
function movePlayer(e:Event):void {
    player.x = stage.mouseX;
    // Doesn't go off the right or left side.
    if (player.x < 0) {
        player.x = 0;
    } else if (player.x > (stage.stageWidth - player.width)) {
        player.x = stage.stageWidth - player.width;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could edit this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the % (modulus) operator to calculate a new position value. Something like:

```
player.x = player.x % this.stage.stageWidth;
```

Comment: Or rather replace all the code inside `movePlayer` with: `player.x = stage.mouseX % stage.stageWidth;`  - though I'm not sure how the OP plans to have it wrap based off mouse position (which can never be greater than the stage width)

Comment: It's meant to be on a mobile device so it's to do with the accelerometer opposed to the position of the mouse.  Hence why I want it flow from one side to the other as I feel it would suit the way the character moves more. I'll try these suggestions though!

Comment: I found this piece of coding for the kind of movement I want: 



if (x > stageRef.stageWidth)
    x = 0;
   else if (x < 0)
    x = stageRef.stageWidth;
 
   if (y > stageRef.stageHeight)
    y = 0;
   else if (y < 0)
    y = stageRef.stageHeight;
However, I don't have the stageRef in my application so I'm unsure as to how to work it in. :(

Comment: "stageRef" is probably just "this.stage" when in your Main class and the writer just stored it in "stageRef" and passed it as needed